# US Citizen - Italy on Covid-tested flight to Croatia, transit Italy to return to the USA?

Tags: usa, covid-19, italy, croatia

Italy should allow for a covid vaccine passport within a few weeks, however, to prepare for the worst, I am assuming that current travel restrictions stay enforced through August.

I am planning a trip from JFK/BOS -> FCO -> DBV, then DBV -> FCO -> JFK/BOS.

The JFK/BOS -> FCO segment, if flown via Delta/Alitalia should be allowed, regardless of transit rules, due to it being [a covid-tested flight](https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/dettaglioContenutiNuovoCoronavirus.jsp?lingua=english&id=5412&area=nuovoCoronavirus&menu=vuoto&tab=8).

FCO -> DBV is [allowed with proof of vaccination as a US citizen](https://hr.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-2)

FCO -> JFK/BOS is [allowed as a US citizen, if a covid test is taken, regardless of vaccination status](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html)

Now, my questions:

1. Is the DBV -> FCO segment allowed, if I do NOT leave the airport? Italian law claims that anyone being in a List D country (USA) within the last 14 days MUST quarantine for 10 days. How does this apply if I previously entered Italy and left?
2. Would I be allowed to transit Italy to Croatia, if I do NOT leave the airport in Italy? Multiple sources tell me that I can transit Italy by "[private means](https://wiki.unece.org/display/CTRBSBC/Italy)" if I do NOT stay in Italy for more than 36 hours. Does "private means" include an airplane?

Comment: If things remain as they are, US citizens won't be allowed into the Schengen Area just as non-US citizens generally aren't allowed into the US when coming directly from the Schengen Area. For Europe this situation will probably change by July, depending on the situation. For the US, to my knowledge, no hint has been given that they will reciprocate in kind.

Comment: Italy is open to US tourists on COVID-tested flights, despite being in the Schengen Area. Multiple countries in the Schengen area have made exceptions ahead of the EU's decision. This is not entirely correct.

Comment: One lesson learned from the last year is that the situation can *swiftly* change. In the UK there is still concern about the Delta variant (B.1.617.2) and it is estimated that another two weeks are needed to get a realistic estimate if it will be contained or spread like wildfire as did the Alpha variant (B.1.1.7) six months ago.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.